# How to remove first word from variable in SMARTY

Tags: php, smarty

I need remove first word from variable in SMARTY.
For example: 
From `"Hello stack. I need help"` to `" stack. I need help"`.

My code:

```
<h1>{$article.title|strstr:' ':true}<thin> another</thin></h1>
```

Thx for help.

Comment: perhaps you could give latest version of the code you've been trying? an we could improve upon it

Comment: Next time [edit] your question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: @martsIf if my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. Otherwise write how you solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `regex_replace` function with the regex `^(\w+\s)` that will replace the first word of a string with space:

```
  {assign var="oldString" value="Hello stack. I need help"}
  {assign var="newString" value=$oldString|regex_replace:"/^(\w+\s)/":" "}
  {$newString|var_dump}
```

**OR**

```
  {"Hello stack. I need help"|regex_replace:"/^(\w+\s)/":" "}
```